# Does std::chrono::system_clock::now() use mutex inside?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-chrono

So the question is: Does std::chrono::system_clock::now() use mutex inside ? So if will run this method I will lock threads.

Comment: It is thread-safe, yes. Whether a mutex is used is implementation-defined.

Comment: @DeiDei - it's implementation-specific, but not implementation-defined. The latter is a term of art in the language definition; it requires that an implementation document its behavior.